# How to return a joined table with last matched results from the second table?

Tags: mysql

TableOne excerpt:

```
┌─product─────┬────────────sequence─┬─qty─┐
│ A18         │ 1534334750278856541 │   7 │
└─────────────┴─────────────────────┴─────┘
```

TableTwo excerpt:

```
┌────────────sequence─┬─product─────┬─size─┐
│ 1534331161780089544 │ A18         │    3 │
│ 1534333381672627454 │ A18         │    3 │
│ 1534334750278856540 │ A18         │    3 │
│ 1534334750278856540 │ A18         │    7 │
│ 1534334750278856540 │ A18         │    5 │
└─────────────────────┴─────────────┴──────┘
```

For each row of TableOne, I would like to find the last row in TableTwo with the same product name and TableTwo.sequence <= TableOne.sequence

So given the sample data above, the return result should be as follows:

```
TableOne.product  = A18
TableOne.qty      = 7
TableOne.sequence = 1534334750278856541 
TableTwo.sequence = 1534334750278856540
TableTwo.size     = 5
```

Thank you

Comment: why  tableTwo.size = 5 and not 7  ... ?  7 have the same criteria  of 5  ..

Comment: You have multiple rows that fit the criteria. How do you choose among them? Is there another column that can be maximized?

Comment: @scaisEdge, TableOne.qty is different from TableTwo.size

Comment: also  Two.size = 3 is different  ..

Comment: @Barmar, for a row in TableOne, you take the product and timestamp, then look for the last row in TableTwo with the same product when TableTwo.sequence <= TableOne.sequence

Comment: @q0987 Rows don't have any built-in ordering, you need a column to order them by.

Comment: in your question there si not  a timestamp ref ...

Comment: @q0987 What timestamp?

Comment: Sorry, I mean sequence number.

Comment: But there are rows with the same sequence number, how do we choose which one to use?

Answer (score 2):

First write a subquery that finds the sequence number in `tableTwo` that fits the criteria:

```
SELECT t1.product, t1.sequence AS t1_sequence, t1.qty, MAX(t2.sequence) AS t2_sequence
FROM tableOne AS t1
JOIN tableTwo AS t2 ON t1.product = t2.t2.product AND t1.SEQUENCE >= t2.sequence
GROUP BY t1.product
```

Then join this with `tableTwo` to find the whole row containing that sequence.

```
SELECT product, t1_sequence, t2_sequence, qty, t2_sequence, t2.size
FROM (
    SELECT t1.product, t1.sequence AS t1_sequence, t1.qty, MAX(t2.sequence) AS t2_sequence
    FROM tableOne AS t1
    JOIN tableTwo AS t2 ON t1.product = t2.t2.product AND t1.SEQUENCE >= t2.sequence
    GROUP BY t1.product
) AS joined
JOIN tableTwo AS t2 ON t2.product = joined.product AND t2.sequence = joined.t2_sequence
```